# Is there a saying in English similar to Croatian "Mate-matematika, ljuta je k'o paprika!" (meaning "I don't like maths!")?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains

Is there a saying in English similar to Croatian "Mate-matematika, ljuta je k'o paprika!"? The Croatian phrase literally translates to "Ma-ma-maths, it is as hot as chili-pepper!" (that is, "I don't like maths!"), but it does not rhyme in English.

Comment: Perhaps also explain what the saying means.  Does it mean "I don't like maths" ... does it mean "Maths is the key to getting a good job" ... or what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GEdgar OK, I edited it to make it more clear that the phrase means "I don't like maths!".

Comment: I've changed the tag to 'idiom requests' to hopefully pre-empt trivial answers, free combinations like 'I don't like math/s' and 'Math/s [really] sucks'. Sayings are idiomatic, while 'phrases' covers any grammatical string.

Comment: 'Latin is a language as dead as dead can be; it killed the ancient Romans, and now it's killing me'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - still much in use in the Vatican, though.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHarvey, those are things I was looking for.

Comment: I found the sentence I quoted written by a previous user on the title page of a school Latin textbook, around 1963.